# stm32 ADC interrupt

Tags: stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm studying ADC programming on STM32 F407 Discovery and starting with the simplest case - single conversion. (connected to ADC1)
I'm using StdPeriph In normal case when I don't using interrupt and do it in while(1) in main() everything is working but when I want to trigger Analog to Digital Converter by interrput value of measurement is set to 0

```
 void ADC_Config(){
   //purposly ommited
    }

void InitializeTimer_OnehundredthSecond(){
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
        TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;


    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period =99;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 8399;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode =  TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}

void TIM4_NVIC_Config(){
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
            // numer przerwania
            NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
            // priorytet główny
            NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
            // subpriorytet
            NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
            // uruchom dany kanał
            NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
            // zapisz wypełnioną strukturę do rejestrów
            NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

            // wyczyszczenie przerwania od timera 4 (wystąpiło przy konfiguracji timera)
            TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update);
            // zezwolenie na przerwania od przepełnienia dla 4
            TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
}
int j=0;
int volatile ADC_Result=0;
void TIM4_IRQHandler(void)
{

    if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
    {

        ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADC1);


        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update);
    }
}


void ADC1_1_IRQHandler(){

            while(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC) == RESET);
            ADC_Result = ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);

}

int main(){


     ADC_Config();
     InitializeTimer_OnehundredthSecond();
     TIM4_NVIC_Config();
     TIM4_IRQHandler();
     ADC1_1_IRQHandler();
    while(1){


    }

}
```

Comment: I would advice the bare register approach instead this bloatware. You have a very good polish tutorial here: https://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic3111562.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your ADC interrupt handler is never called.
If you look at your startup file (`startup_stm32f407xx.s`), you can see that the interrupt handler is:

> DCD     ADC_IRQHandler                    ; ADC1, ADC2 and ADC3s

In your code, you have:

```
void ADC1_1_IRQHandler()
```

which is never called. So your variable stays at 0.

So rename `ADC1_1_IRQHandler` into `ADC_IRQHandler` and that should work.

If this does not save your issue, please share the code for `ADC_Config`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code. I've already solved that problem. Invoking IRQ  like I did in main is a bad idea.:/

```
   void InitializeTimer_OnehundredthSecond(){
        RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
            TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;


        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period =99;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 8399;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode =  TIM_CounterMode_Up;
        TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    }

    void TIM4_NVIC_Config(){
        NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
                // numer przerwania
                NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
                // priorytet główny
                NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
                // subpriorytet
                NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
                // uruchom dany kanał
                NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
                // zapisz wypełnioną strukturę do rejestrów
                NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

                // wyczyszczenie przerwania od timera 4 (wystąpiło przy konfiguracji timera)
                TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update);
                // zezwolenie na przerwania od przepełnienia dla 4
                TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    }
    int j=0;
    int volatile ADC_Result=0;

    void TIM4_IRQHandler(void)
    {
        if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
        {

            ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADC1);


                TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update);
        }
    }



    void ADC1_1_NVIC_Config(){

        NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;


                    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = ADC_IRQn;
                    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
                    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
                    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
                    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

                    ADC_ClearITPendingBit(ADC1,ADC_IT_EOC);
                    ADC_ITConfig(ADC1, ADC_IT_EOC, ENABLE);



    }




    void ADC_IRQHandler(){

        if(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC) != RESET){
        ADC_Result = ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);


            //ADC_ClearITPendingBit(ADC1,ADC_FLAG_EOC);//<--clear automatically
        }
    }

    int main(){



         ADC_Config();
         NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_1);
         ADC1_1_NVIC_Config();
         InitializeTimer_OnehundredthSecond();
         TIM4_NVIC_Config();
         TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
        while(1){



        }

    }
```